# Adding a new child item to a datasource for a rendering

Tags: content-editor, experience-editor

I have a rendering that has a Datasource Template of a menu container. When I change the datasource of the rendering, I can create a new Menu Container. But I would also like to add a new menu item to that container via the UI.

I imagine its a custom button in the ribbon of the rendering and a Edit Frame for the item properties? Are there any guidelines I could follow to accomplish this?

Comment: What about http://davegoosem.net/web-development/sitecore/add-edit-reorder-delete-content-sitecore-page-editor/ ?

Comment: Looking at that right now. Let me implement it and see if it does what we need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a straight-forward way to add an Insert button to the Edit Frame of components.

## Set Experience Editor Buttons

Sitecore comes with some Custom Experience Buttons which can be added to renderings. To achieve what you want, add the *Insert* one to your rendering:

[image: Adding Insert button to rendering]

When added, you'll see the icon appear in the Edit Frame of the rendering:

[image: Demo of edit frame with insert button]

## Set the Insert Options

When the Insert button is clicked, it triggers a dialog that allows the user to select a template to insert. The templates that are shown are based on the *Insert Options* of the datasource template's Standard Values, so you should make sure you add the valid templates there.

Comment: I'm reminded of the time Neo from the Matrix says "HOLY ___". Very helpful. Thank you.